# Kivy video not deinterlaced

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm developing a GUI with a video player. I'm using the `Video` widget, but on play I can see that my video is not/badly deinterlaced, and that some lines appears on the frame. My video is a high res video, and I have no problem playing it on my system player, only in Kivy.
I have looked in the documentation of both kivy and ffpyplayer, and nothing seems to mention deinterlacing

My code so far is simply

```py
class MyVideoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.player = Video(source='video.MTS', state='play',
                                  options={'allow_stretch': False})
        return (self.player)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyVideoApp().run()
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to pass the needed parameters to the ffmpeg player used by Kivy, so instead I converted the videos with ffmpeg before passing them to kivy... Not a perfect solution, but hey, it works !